# Flatsome responsive wooCommerce theme checkout page issue

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

we are facing an issue on checkout page , the page become unresponsive after 2-3 sec . while if we switch to WordPress defaults  themes then everything is working fine and smooth.So we think that the issue is in theme only.we had updated all our installed plugin including woocommerce version . while we have wordpress version 4.2.4. The issue only occurs on checkout page.Our site URL is http://www.giftaselfie.com/.

Comment: contact support to flatsome theme which you buy. . .

Comment: Agree to contact theme support. There is possibly a Javascript error.

Comment: thanks for your reply , we had checked it by disabling the javascript .it works by doing that, then we checked all our js files to find the bug and also tried by removing all js files of theme, but the problem is not solved yet. even we updated the theme now our theme version is flatsome 2.6